# Generate PDF with Print PDF and send in email

Tags: files, rules, emails

When a user registers he has to select some options that will be defining for the invoice created afterwards.

I have a rule that will be executed when saving a user account. This is what I do:

- Rule 1: Create Invoice (invoice = content type) and Save Invoice
- Rule 2: Fill in Invoice

The invoice is generated when a user registers an account. When I go to the invoice like this:

```
http://domain.com/node/147294
```

I see the Invoice. When I go to `http://domain.com/printpdf/147294` I get a pdf with my content in it.

Now I would like to create a pdf and send it in a mail to the user that is registrated (an extra rule). But how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to attach this pdf file or just the link?

Comment: attach the pdf file...

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this modules:

**Views PDF**

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is added.

https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf

**Views PDF Mime Mail**

> This module provides the integration of Views PDF and Mime Mail.
>   This allows the user to send a View as a PDF to a customer by Rules.

https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf_mimemail

Comment: The views_pdf_mimemail module appears abandoned. Is it possible to create the functionality the OP required using just the views_pdf module and Rules?