# How to create and send via email a PDF file with rules?

Tags: 7, rules, files, views

I need to create and send via email a PDF file with Rules using Drupal 7. I need to send it as an attachment, not as a link.

I found this post,  [Generate PDF with Print PDF and send in email](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114667/generate-pdf-with-print-pdf-and-send-in-email), but [Views PDF MIMEMail](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf_mimemail) is a D6 module.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a port to Drupal 7. The Views PDF MIMEMail module [codebase](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_pdf_mimemail/tree/?h=6.x-1.x) is pretty lightweight (~300 LOC). Essentially, it's a

1. **.info** file declaration
2. A **.module** declaring a theme function
3. Various Rules integration functions (**.rules.inc**).

You can figure out how to convert the **.info** & **.module** by Googling around how to convert a **.info** to D7 and look up how [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) changed in D7. There's a [comprehensive guide](https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7) on porting D6 modules to D7 if needed.

As for #3, the Rules module has some [internal documentation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules/tree/rules.api.php?h=7.x-2.10) that describes how to integrate Rules in D7. There's likely a few structural changes you'll need to do, but essentially most PHP code should stay the same.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Link updated